# Query relationship Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have `News` model, and `News` has many comments, so I did this in `News` model:

```
public function comments(){
    $this->hasMany('Comment', 'news_id');
}
```

But I also have field `trashed` in `comments` table, and I only want to select comments that are not trashed. So `trashed <> 1`. So I wonder is there a way to do something like this:

```
$news = News::find(123);
$news->comments->where('trashed', '<>', 1); //some sort of pseudo-code
```

Is there a way to use above method or should I just write something like this:

```
$comments = Comment::where('trashed', '<>', 1)
    ->where('news_id', '=', $news->id)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Any of these should work for you, pick the one you like the most:

1. Eager-loading.

   ```
   $comments = News::find(123)->with(['comments' => function ($query) {
       $query->where('trashed', '<>', 1);
   }])->get();
   ```

   You can inject the parameter to query function by `use($param)` method, that allows you to use dynemic query value at runtime.
2. Lazy-loading

   ```
   $news = News::find(123);
   $comments = $news->comments()->where('trashed', '<>', 1)->get();
   ```

---

I couldn't help but notice, though, that what you're probably trying to do is handle soft deleting, and that Laravel has built-in functionality to help you with that: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: I have implemented soft delete, but I also wanted comments unpublished but not deleted. I have delete option too

Answer (score 18):

You can do simply in your eloquent model file.
do like this :

```
public function comments_with_deleted()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Comments', 'id')->where('deleted', 1);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Comments', 'id');
}
```

call like this :

```
// for show comments with deleted
$comments = News::find(123)->with('comments_with_deleted');

// for show comments without deleted
$comments = News::find(123)->with('comments');
```

Answer (score 16):

**rmobis**'s answer was what I needed, but it throws an error in current Laravel 5. You have to use it as an associatve array now:

```
$comments = News::find(123)->with(['comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('trashed', '<>', 1);
}]);
```

Took me some time to figure it out, hope this will help others.

Read more in Laravel's Docs (5.6): https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 10.22.0, it worked after calling first() function at the end

```
$comments = News::with('comments')->where('id',123)->first();
```