# Query Laravel Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Just as title say, i want to query query relationships(plural).
I saw numerous examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036269/query-relationship-eloquent)

which work well. But it's querying only one relationship.

Can it just:

```
Vehicle::with("deliveries", "user", "type", "workOrganization")->get();
```

go like this:

```
Vehicle::with("deliveries", "1", "user", "1", "type", "1", "workOrganization", "1")->get();
```

where number "1" is an id.
Or are those two ways for this, are only ways to approach this?

And i want to say, any of these ids are optional, so that even muddies the water even further...

Answer (score 1):

You can but you have to split them like:

```
Vehicle::whereHas('deliveries', function (Builder $query) {
     $query->where('deliveries.id', '=', '1');
})->get();
```

And so on and so forth. Just giving you the first example to get an idea of how to approach it.

If it's optional then you can use a `when` clause passing a variable and check it like this in your query before you use a relationship so something like:

```
$deliveriedId = null;

    Vehicle::when(!empty($deliverieId), function ($q) {
          return $q->whereHas('deliveries', function (Builder $query) {
              $query->where('deliveries.id', '=', '1');
          })
       });
```

Basically the above code will check if your variable is not empty and then and only then will use the relationship `deliveries` to filter out your results. This normally comes from the `request`.

So that way you make it optional when to use and not not like you stated in your question.